# swift table view won't show images in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that I populate from an remote api. I then load images into the table view asynchronous.

I have a fixed row height, then I have set the uiimageview constraints to **top:0 left:0 bottom:0 width:120** togther with aspect fill.

If a image is in landscape mode it will show up. But images in portrait mode does not show up in my table views cells.

Is it my contraints that fails?

It scales all landscape images right.

thanks,

Comment: We can't help you by guessing what your code looks like. Please post some code.

Comment: you can set a background color to your UIImageView to see if it's visible in portrait, and use the View Hierarchy debugger to see the position of the UIImageView in portrait

Comment: Try to find out the frame of UIImageView when it is in landscape mode.